# automatically remove link parameter in the page onload

Tags: split, removeall

I want to change all html links automatically removing the "#url=", for example

`http://savefrom.net/#url=http://youtube.com/watch?v=xxx`

into

`http://savefrom.net/http://youtube.com/watch?v=xxx`

Is there a JavaScript or Jquery solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
'http://savefrom.net/#url=http://youtube.com/watch?v=xxx'.replace('#url=','')
```